# How to view the build console output in jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins

I am using Master & Slave jenkins, The connection between master & slave configured using ssh-slave plugin.

To view build console output (From Initial step to final step) in slave system itself, there is a plugin that need to be configured in Job's  post-build section. (Which generates at last)

But i m looking to fetch/view the console output of my job in workspace itself. Right from SCM checkout step itself.

Means I want to view my SCM checkout step console output log in workspace immediately as soon as i triggered the build.

This is required to capture certain strings & pass in code compilation & in static analysis steps..

I can see that Jenkins stores all logs in master server.

So any suggestion will help us. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "pre-build" that you're referring to? It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Maratc, I have updated the question.

Comment: It's highly unlikely there is something in the log that you can't get otherwise. You should analyze the output of the commands you run, not rely on reading the log.